# "You have a bad feeling about this basement"

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In Thundermar when you enter a certain basement you get the warning message "You have a bad feeling about this basement...". Inside there is a spider, which is definitely not a threat to anyone who happens to be there.

What's the point? Am I missing something? Is that some sort of tribute to something I don't know?

Comment: The tribute is clearly to Star Wars. I don't play WoW so I don't know about the rest.

Comment: @dierre: post it as an answer ;)

Comment: Since I don't play WoW I could not be sure about your question besides the SW reference.

Answer (score 5):

This is one of 4 random (but very commonly) spawning encounters that make up the [Wildhammer Tour of Duty](http://www.wowhead.com/achievement=5481) achievement.

Comment: Yes it is, but what does this have to do with my question? :/

Comment: You asked what the point is. The point is to be part of the achievement. The encounter serves no other purpose, aside from providing a fun Star Wars Easter Egg.

Comment: Should we assume this is The Black Recluse spawn point?

Comment: @powerlord yes.